# Make Query Data Become Link

Tags: php, html, postgresql

As mentioned in the title, I would like to know how can I make the queried data become a link to another php file. For example, referring to the pic attached below, I would like to show all the cities of United States by just simply click on it and same goes with United Kingdom. I want to make like when I click on any of the state, the php file link to it will automatically know which state I've selected and generate its corresponding cities.

[image]

The following is my code:

```
<html>

  <head><title>State</title></head>

<body>

<?php

 $dbh = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=state user=postgres");

if (!$dbh) {
    die("Error in connection: " . pg_last_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM state ";



 echo "<table>";
 echo "<table border=\"1\" align=\"center\">";
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<th>ID</th>";
 echo "<th>State</th>";
 echo "</tr>";


$result = pg_query($dbh, $sql);

if (!$result) {

    die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());

}

while ($column = pg_fetch_array($result)) {

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$column[0]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$column[1]."</td>";   
echo "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";


pg_free_result($result);


pg_close($dbh);


?>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This isn't difficult at all. What have you tried?

Comment: @JohnConde ya sorry but I'm new...I can create normal link..but I don't know how to create link for query data..could be you be kind to give me some guide...thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need to wrap the column with Anchor tags and if you store the link in the db you can make that the Anchor source.

Comment: @abushahin <a href= echo "<td>".$column[0]."</td>""state.php"></a>...how should I exactly adding to it..thx.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your current php file:

```
// Replace your while statement in your code above with this...
$row_counter = 0; 
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result,$row_counter,PGSQL_ASSOC)) { 

   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
   echo "<td><a href='state.php?id=".$row['id']."'>".htmlentities($row['state'])."</a></td>";
   echo "</tr>"; 

   $row_counter++; 
}
```

And in another php file, let's say *state.php*, you could run something like this:

```
$state_id = $_GET['state_id'];

// connect to database...

$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE state_id = '".pg_escape_string($state_id)."'";

// run your query...
```

Note: `htmlentities` will prevent XSS problems and `pg_escape_string` will help prevent SQL injection (but research [prepared statements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-prepare.html) for a better approach).

Comment: thanks a lot man..I'm checking this out

Comment: And eventually you'll want to separate your PHP code from your HTML code. Having them together like this can get real messy, real fast. Something like "state.php" and "state_view.php", where state_view.php would have only HTML and a few PHP variables or at most a simple loop. You could "include" this file from state.php and just pass over the variables. Ideally you would eventually create some sort of class to handle passing your data from PHP to your view. Study MVC design pattern. Good luck, select my answer if it helped.

Comment: I also updated my answer to include `htmlentities` (to guard from XSS) and `pg_escape_string` (to guard from SQL injection).

Comment: sorry sorry...just now was busy coding...I've accepted and voted it up..thanks again!